# Regular Expression to Match both Capital and Lower Characters

Tags: regex

I am writing script for screening words within contents and replace it with ***, if matched.

I am using the following simple regular expression for screening words like apple, banana

```
(\bbanana|apple\b)
```

It match all words **banana** and **apple** within content but not **Apple** or **aPPle** etc.

I want to write regular expression which match word regardless which character is capital or lower.

If i replace content to lower characters it will solve problem, but i want to keep content in original state.

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: php but my question is related to regular expression. rest code working fine.

Comment: Just Google "php regex case insensitive".

Comment: the lang question is valid, since different langs have different formats for regexes.

Comment: ok i posted function which perform screening

Comment: **Are you not using the regex modifier `\i` on purpose**, or do you just not know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like  this:-

```
/[A-Z]{3}([0-9]{1,4})?|[A-Z]{1,3}/i
```

In your case:-

```
/\b(banana|apple)\b/i
```

Answer (score 1):

the /i switch does case-insensitive matching:

```
/\b(banana|apple)\b/i
```

I also moved your word boundary markers outside of the alternation.